# Error response from daemon: manifest for quay.io/phpseclib/php8.1:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

Per https://quay.io/repository/phpseclib/php8.1 I should be able to pull down that Docker container by doing `docker pull quay.io/phpseclib/php8.1` but when I try I get this error:

```
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for quay.io/phpseclib/php8.1:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Quay the issue was that the "latest" tag didn't exist. The git repo I was pulling from didn't have a latest tag but it had an 8.1 tag so if I didn't want to use a custom tagging template I could do this:

```
docker pull quay.io/phpseclib/php8.1:8.1
```

Using a custom tagging template is another approach. Just type in latest into the "Enter a tag template" text field and then click the "Add Tag Template" button.

Comment: Hello did you find the solution this problem ? I'm facing the same error using Nexus has proxy registry ?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/a/1096763/166832 ! Not sure how applicable that is to Nexus.